# Is the "System RAM" displayed by /proc/iomem is like unallocated memory?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I could figure out other memory map info like few are device bus specific memory
I want to know like
What is the System RAM means here..

```
0000000-0000ffff : reserved
00010000-0009c3ff : System RAM
0009c400-0009ffff : reserved
000a0000-000bffff : PCI Bus 0000:00
  000a0000-000bffff : Video RAM area
000c0000-000c7fff : Video ROM
000d0000-000d0fff : Adapter ROM
000d2000-000d3fff : reserved
000d4000-000d7fff : PCI Bus 0000:00
000d8000-000dbfff : PCI Bus 0000:00
000dc000-000dffff : PCI Bus 0000:00
000e0000-000fffff : reserved
  000f0000-000fffff : System ROM
00100000-bb27bfff : System RAM
  01000000-015b0afb : Kernel code
  015b0afc-01878c3f : Kernel data
  01939000-01a11fff : Kernel bss
bb27c000-bb281fff : reserved
bb282000-bb3e9fff : System RAM
bb3ea000-bb40efff : reserved
bb40f000-bb46efff : System RAM
bb46f000-bb46ffff : reserved
bb470000-bb4f0fff : ACPI Non-volatile Storage
bb4f1000-bb70efff : reserved
bb70f000-bb716fff : System RAM
bb717000-bb71efff : reserved
bb71f000-bb77dfff : System RAM
bb77e000-bb79efff : ACPI Non-volatile Storage
bb79f000-bb7e1fff : System RAM
bb7e2000-bb7fefff : ACPI Tables
bb7ff000-bb7fffff : System RAM
bb800000-bfffffff : reserved
c0000000-dfffffff : PCI Bus 0000:00
  c0000000-c04fffff : PCI Bus 0000:04
  c0500000-c06fffff : PCI Bus 0000:03
  c0700000-c08fffff : PCI Bus 0000:02
  c0900000-c0afffff : PCI Bus 0000:02
  c0b00000-c0b00fff : Intel Flush Page
  d0000000-dfffffff : 0000:00:02.0
e0000000-efffffff : PCI MMCONFIG 0000 [bus 00-ff]
  e0000000-efffffff : reserved
    e0000000-efffffff : pnp 00:09
f0000000-febfffff : PCI Bus 0000:00
  f0000000-f03fffff : 0000:00:02.0
  f0400000-f04fffff : PCI Bus 0000:03
    f0400000-f0403fff : 0000:03:00.0
  f0700000-f0703fff : 0000:00:1b.0
    f0700000-f0703fff : ICH HD audio
  f0704000-f0704fff : reserved
    f0704000-f0704fff : 0000:00:1f.6
      f0704000-f0704fff : ips thermal sensor
  f0705000-f07057ff : 0000:00:1f.2
    f0705000-f07057ff : ahci
  f0705800-f070580f : 0000:00:16.0
    f0705800-f070580f : mei
  f0706000-f07063ff : 0000:00:1a.0
    f0706000-f07063ff : ehci_hcd
  f0706400-f07067ff : 0000:00:1d.0
    f0706400-f07067ff : ehci_hcd
  f0706800-f07068ff : 0000:00:1f.3
  f0800000-f08fffff : PCI Bus 0000:04
    f0800000-f080ffff : 0000:04:00.0
      f0800000-f080ffff : r8169
    f0810000-f0810fff : 0000:04:00.0
      f0810000-f0810fff : r8169
    f0820000-f083ffff : 0000:04:00.0
  feaff000-feafffff : reserved
    feaff000-feafffff : pnp 00:09
fec00000-fec0ffff : reserved
  fec00000-fec003ff : IOAPIC 0
fed00000-fed003ff : HPET 0
  fed00000-fed003ff : reserved
fed10000-fed13fff : pnp 00:09
fed18000-fed18fff : pnp 00:09
fed19000-fed19fff : pnp 00:09
fed1c000-fed8ffff : reserved
  fed1c000-fed1ffff : pnp 00:09
  fed20000-fed3ffff : pnp 00:09
  fed40000-fed44fff : pnp 00:09
  fed45000-fed8ffff : pnp 00:09
fee00000-fee00fff : Local APIC
  fee00000-fee00fff : reserved
ff000000-ffffffff : reserved
  ff000000-ffffffff : pnp 00:09
100000000-17bffffff : System RAM
180000000-1bbffffff : System RAM
```

Is that unallocated userspace memory..?

Please make it clear.

Please don't confuse this post with the one here:

[Is System RAM the only section where heap/stack resides?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774889/is-system-ram-the-only-section-where-heap-stack-resides)

Comment: My question is why there are multiple "System RAM" ?

Comment: @satish: Memory map are "not contiguous". So you will be having device specific memory maps interleaved by unallocated memory i.e System RAM.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
0000000-0000ffff : reserved      // Reserved = not used, not available for anything.
00010000-0009c3ff : System RAM   // Regular memory - can be used to store code or data/
0009c400-0009ffff : reserved    
000a0000-000bffff : PCI Bus 0000:00   // PCI device memory case
  000a0000-000bffff : Video RAM area   // (graphics/video memory in this)
000c0000-000c7fff : Video ROM          // VGA BIOS memory
000d0000-000d0fff : Adapter ROM        // General area for "boot ROM", e.g. Network boot
000d2000-000d3fff : reserved    
000d4000-000d7fff : PCI Bus 0000:00   // Some other PCI device
000d8000-000dbfff : PCI Bus 0000:00   // as above
000dc000-000dffff : PCI Bus 0000:00
000e0000-000fffff : reserved
  000f0000-000fffff : System ROM      // System BIOS
00100000-bb27bfff : System RAM        // Regular RAM
  01000000-015b0afb : Kernel code     // Kernel "code" uses this bit.
  015b0afc-01878c3f : Kernel data     // Kernel "data"
  01939000-01a11fff : Kernel bss      // Kernel "initialized to zero" data.
bb27c000-bb281fff : reserved    
bb282000-bb3e9fff : System RAM
bb3ea000-bb40efff : reserved    
bb40f000-bb46efff : System RAM  
bb46f000-bb46ffff : reserved
bb470000-bb4f0fff : ACPI Non-volatile Storage    // Advanced Control and Power Interface memory (doesn't got away when power is off!)
bb4f1000-bb70efff : reserved
bb70f000-bb716fff : System RAM
bb717000-bb71efff : reserved
bb71f000-bb77dfff : System RAM
bb77e000-bb79efff : ACPI Non-volatile Storage 
bb79f000-bb7e1fff : System RAM
bb7e2000-bb7fefff : ACPI Tables
bb7ff000-bb7fffff : System RAM
bb800000-bfffffff : reserved
c0000000-dfffffff : PCI Bus 0000:00
  c0000000-c04fffff : PCI Bus 0000:04     // PCI bus bridge device
```

Comment: Peterson: Clear.. Thanks..! can you brief this a little please.
bb470000-bb4f0fff : ACPI Non-volatile Storage    // Advanced Control and Power Interface memory (doesn't got away when power is off!)

Comment: It would normally be implemented as a NVRam (serial eeprom) - it's "non-volatile", so things can be stored there without the power being on. I don't know exactly how/what it is used for, to be honest.

Comment: Peterson : Okay I figured out, Maybe eeprom is mapped there. when system is shutdown it stores the content of that region to eeprom

Comment: Serial EEPROM is not likely to be mapped into linear memory address space.  Serial EEPROM is usually connected to the system using TWI or I2C or SPI, and the device address space is typically kept local to the serial interface.  (Although Atmel did do a software mapping of DataFlash in U-Boot.)  The ACPI Non-volatile Storage is more likely battery-backed SRAM or parallel flash memory.

Comment: @sawdust, might be battery-backed SRAM, I doubt paralled flash memory

Answer (score 2):

iomem are addresses that map to physical memories and device registers..

The addresses referring to system RAM are termed as physical addresses(to store kernel or user space code and data), and those referring to device maps as bus addresses.

This is largely dependent on the architecture.

[image]

Comment: I could not get like what you are saying. Here, few regions are tagged as "System RAM" I want to know whether this system ram means unallocated memory(user space).